Converting Entity java to kotlin , not able to generate run time file
I have converted one of my entities (SflUser) from Java to Kotlin. After the conversion, I am unable to generate the runtime file named SflUser_ in the project.
I used IntelliJ to convert the whole file. I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but the problem persists not just with one entity but with any entity I convert:
gradle clean then bootRun
Restarting IntelliJ IDEA
Re-converting the entire file
Here is the Kotlin code for the SflUser entity:
and also i had attached build.gradle file at the end.
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@EntityListeners(EntityAuditListener::class)
open class SflUser : Serializable {
 // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here
 @JvmField
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 var id: Long? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "user_name")
 var userName: String? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "email")
 var email: String? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "phone_number")
 var phoneNumber: Long? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "password")
 var password: String? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "image_url")
 var imageUrl: String? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "first_name")
 var firstName: String? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "last_name")
 var lastName: String? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "activation_key")
 var activationKey: String? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "status")
 var status: Boolean? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "reset_key", length = 20)
 @JsonIgnore
 var resetKey: @Size(max = 20) String? = null

 @JvmField
 @Column(name = "reset_date")
 var resetDate: Instant? = null

 @JvmField
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(
     name = "user_authority",
     joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
     inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")]
 )
 @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
 @JsonIgnore
 var authorities: Set<Authority> = HashSet()

 @JvmField
 @OneToOne
 var countryDialCode: CountryDialCode? = null

 fun userName(userName: String?): SflUser {
     this.userName = userName
     return this
 }

 fun email(email: String?): SflUser {
     this.email = email
     return this
 }

 fun phoneNumber(phoneNumber: Long?): SflUser {
     this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
     return this
 }

 fun password(password: String?): SflUser {
     this.password = password
     return this
 }

 fun imageUrl(imageUrl: String?): SflUser {
     this.imageUrl = imageUrl
     return this
 }

 fun firstName(firstName: String?): SflUser {
     this.firstName = firstName
     return this
 }

 fun lastName(lastName: String?): SflUser {
     this.lastName = lastName
     return this
 }

 fun activationKey(activationKey: String?): SflUser {
     this.activationKey = activationKey
     return this
 }

 fun status(status: Boolean?): SflUser {
     this.status = status
     return this
 }

 fun authorities(authorities: Set<Authority>): SflUser {
     this.authorities = authorities
     return this
 }

 
 override fun equals(o: Any?): Boolean {
     if (this === o) {
         return true
     }
     if (o !is SflUser) {
         return false
     }
     return (id != null) && id == o.id
 }

 override fun hashCode(): Int {
     return Objects.hashCode(id)
 }

 // prettier-ignore
 override fun toString(): String {
     return ObjectSerializer.serialize(this)
 }

 companion object {
     private const val serialVersionUID = 1L
 }
}

**Gradle file:**

buildscript {
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
 repositories {
     mavenLocal()
     mavenCentral()
     gradlePluginPortal()
     maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
 }
 dependencies {
     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
     //jhipster-needle-gradle-buildscript-dependency - JHipster will add additional gradle build script plugins here
 }
}

plugins {
 id "java"
 id "maven-publish"
 id "idea"
 id "jacoco"
 id "org.springframework.boot" version("2.6.4")
 id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib"
 id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties"
 id "org.liquibase.gradle"
 id "org.sonarqube"
 id "io.spring.nohttp"

 //jhipster-needle-gradle-plugins - JHipster will add additional gradle plugins here
}

group = "com.sfl.core"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

description = ""

sourceCompatibility=1.17
targetCompatibility=1.17
assert System.properties["java.specification.version"] == "1.8" || "11" || "12" || "13" || "14" || "15" || "16" || "17"

apply from: "gradle/docker.gradle"
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply from: "gradle/sonar.gradle"
apply plugin: 'war'

//jhipster-needle-gradle-apply-from - JHipster will add additional gradle scripts to be applied here

if (project.hasProperty("prod") || project.hasProperty("gae")) {
 apply from: "gradle/profile_prod.gradle"
} else if (project.hasProperty("dev")) {
apply from: "gradle/profile_dev.gradle"
} else {
 apply from: "gradle/profile_local.gradle"
}

if (project.hasProperty("war")) {
 apply from: "gradle/war.gradle"
}

if (project.hasProperty("gae")) {
 apply plugin: 'maven'
 apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot.experimental.thin-launcher'
 apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

 dependencyManagement {
     imports {
         mavenBom "io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipster_dependencies_version}"
     }
 }
 appengineStage.dependsOn thinResolve
}

if (project.hasProperty("zipkin")) {
 apply from: "gradle/zipkin.gradle"
}


defaultTasks "bootRun"

springBoot {
 mainClass = "com.sfl.core.SflCoreApp"
}

bootWar {
 mainClass = 'com.sfl.core.SflCoreApp'
}

war {

}

test {
 useJUnitPlatform()
 exclude "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"

 testLogging {
     events 'FAILED', 'SKIPPED'
 }
 // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
 // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
 // ignoreFailures true
 reports.html.enabled = false
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
 useJUnitPlatform()
 description = "Execute integration tests."
 group = "verification"
 include "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"

 testLogging {
     events 'FAILED', 'SKIPPED'
 }

 if (project.hasProperty('testcontainers')) {
     environment 'spring.profiles.active', 'testcontainers'
 }

 // uncomment if the tests reports are not generated
 // see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2771 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/4484
 // ignoreFailures true
 reports.html.enabled = false
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
 destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
 reportOn test
}

task integrationTestReport(type: TestReport) {
 destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests")
 reportOn integrationTest
}

if (!project.hasProperty("runList")) {
 project.ext.runList = "main"
}

project.ext.diffChangelogFile = "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/" + new Date().format("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_changelog.xml"

liquibase {
 activities {
     main {
         driver "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
         url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sflcore"
         username "root"
         password ""
         changeLogFile "src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml"
         defaultSchemaName "sflcore"
         logLevel "debug"
         classpath "src/main/resources/"
     }
     diffLog {
         driver "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
         url "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sflcore"
         username "root"
         password ""
         changeLogFile project.ext.diffChangelogFile
         referenceUrl "hibernate:spring:com.sfl.core.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy"
         defaultSchemaName "sflcore"
         logLevel "debug"
         classpath "$buildDir/classes/java/main"
     }
 }

 runList = project.ext.runList
}

gitProperties {
 failOnNoGitDirectory = false
 keys = ["git.branch", "git.commit.id.abbrev", "git.commit.id.describe"]
}

checkstyle {
 toolVersion '${checkstyle_version}'
 configFile file("checkstyle.xml")
 checkstyleTest.enabled = false
}
nohttp {
 source.include "build.gradle"
}

configurations {
providedRuntime
 implementation.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
 all {
     resolutionStrategy {
         // Inherited version from Spring Boot can't be used because of regressions:
         // To be removed as soon as spring-boot use the same version
         force 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.9.0'
     }
 }
}

repositories {
 maven() {
     credentials {
         username "$nexusUser"
         password "$nexusPassword"
     }
     url "https://nexus.thesunflowerlab.com/repository/sunflowerlab-releases"
 }
 mavenLocal()
 mavenCentral()
 jcenter()
 //jhipster-needle-gradle-repositories - JHipster will add additional repositories
}

dependencies {
 // import JHipster dependencies BOM
 if (!project.hasProperty("gae")) {
     implementation platform("io.github.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipster_dependencies_version}")
 }
 implementation "org.reflections:reflections:0.10.2"

 // Use ", version: jhipster_dependencies_version, changing: true" if you want
 // to use a SNAPSHOT release instead of a stable release
 implementation group: "io.github.jhipster", name: "jhipster-framework"
 implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache"
 implementation "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core"
 implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus"
 implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder"
 implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc"
 implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
 implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations"
 implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5"
 implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
 implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
 implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast"
 implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-hibernate53"
 implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring"
 implementation "javax.cache:cache-api"
 implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
 implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP"
 implementation "javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api"
 implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager"
 implementation "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator"
 implementation "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
 liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
 implementation "com.sfl.lib.core:twilioutil:1.0.4.4.RELEASE:dependency@jar"
 implementation "com.twilio.sdk:twilio:8.0.0"
 liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:${liquibase_hibernate5_version}"
 liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:${spring_boot_version}"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:${spring_boot_version}"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:${spring_boot_version}"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${spring_boot_version}"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${spring_boot_version}"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${spring_boot_version}"
 testImplementation "org.testcontainers:mysql"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${spring_boot_version}"
 implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${spring_boot_version}") {
     exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"

 }
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:${spring_boot_version}"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${spring_boot_version}"
 implementation "org.zalando:problem-spring-web"
 implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:2.1.2.RELEASE"
 implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:3.1.0"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors"
 implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
 implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-data"
 implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"
 implementation group: 'org.javers', name: 'javers-core', version: '6.1.0'
 implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.30.11'
 implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '5.0.0-alpha.2'
 implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api"
 if(Boolean.parseBoolean("$notification")){
     implementation 'com.sfl.lib.core:notification:2.0.8.5.RELEASE:dependency@jar'
     implementation group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-admin', version: '6.13.0'
 }
 if (!project.hasProperty("gae")) {
     runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl"
     runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson"
 } else {
     implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl"
     implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson"
 }

 implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
 liquibaseRuntime "mysql:mysql-connector-java"
 implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapstruct_version}"
 annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstruct_version}"
 annotationProcessor "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:${hibernate_version}"
 annotationProcessor "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxb_runtime_version}"
 annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${spring_boot_version}"
 testImplementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
     exclude group: "org.junit.vintage", module: "junit-vintage-engine"
 }
 testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test"
 testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test"
 testImplementation "com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5-api:${archunit_junit5_version}"
 testRuntimeOnly "com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5-engine:${archunit_junit5_version}"
 testImplementation "com.h2database:h2"
 implementation "org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.3.15"
 implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-loadbalancer:3.1.1"
 implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.6"
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

}

if (project.hasProperty("gae")) {
 task createPom {
     def basePath = 'build/resources/main/META-INF/maven'
     doLast {
         pom {
             withXml(dependencyManagement.pomConfigurer)
         }.writeTo("${basePath}/${project.group}/${project.name}/pom.xml")
     }
 }
 bootJar.dependsOn = [createPom]
}

task cleanResources(type: Delete) {
 delete "build/resources"
}

task stage(dependsOn: 'bootWar') {
}

wrapper {
 gradleVersion = "7.3"
}

compileJava.dependsOn processResources
processResources.dependsOn bootBuildInfo
compileKotlin {
 kotlinOptions {
     jvmTarget = "17"
 }
}
compileTestKotlin {
 kotlinOptions {
     jvmTarget = "17"
 }
}


show your maven (pox.xml) or gradle file.

i had added the build.gradle file at the end of the entity,could you please check @life888888

Goto Spring Initializr ( https://start.spring.io/ )  Project: Gradle - Groovy  , Language: Kotlin ....  , Dependencies add ( Spring Web , Spring Data JPA, Spring Data Redis (Access+Driver) , then GENERATE , compare, build.gradle ,  dependencies { ,  you don't have :  "implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'" ,
"implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'"

@life888888
still getting the same error:
cannot find symbol
import com.sfl.core.domain.SflUser_;
^
symbol:   class SflUser_
location: package com.sfl.core.domain

build.gradle add "implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation' " for  var resetKey: @Size(max = 20) String? = null

still there is the same error @life888888
